# Qt, loading and modifying web pages

Tags: javascript, qt, dom

after a fair bit of googling mentioning in particular QWebkit and QDomDocument, I have understood the current Qt way to load and modify web pages was to load them into QWebEnginePage(s) and run Javascript into these to query and modify the DOM.

Am I correct in my understanding that there is no current Qt/C++ to access the DOM of a web page? And that QWebEnginePage(s) and Javascript are the easiest way to do so?

Comment: you can create your own `Qt\C++` object and inject it to the `QWebEnginePage`  to bind between C++ and JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `QWebEngine` there's no direct way to access/modify the `DOM` without JavaScript/C++ binding using the [QWebChannel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html#details)

It was possible to access the `DOM` directly from Qt\C++ using the [QWebElement](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html#details)
Although that `QWebView` is [deprecated](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5#Deprecated_Functionality) in Qt 5.5

Comment: Is QWebEnginePage->runJavascript() using a QWebChannel under the hood?